# browser shows 404 error

Tags: java, servlets

I am new to servlet and making my first servlet using eclipse.I have made Index.html, Login.java and WelcomeServlet.java. But whenever I am trying to access the using

```
localhost:8080/ServletExample/
```

It shows 404 error.Here are the codes..

**Index.html**

```
<form action="Login" method="post">  
Name:<input type="text" name="userName"/><br/>  
Password:<input type="password" name="userPass"/><br/>  
<input type="submit" value="login"/>  
</form>
```

**Login.java**

```
public class Login extends HttpServlet {  

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
            throws ServletException, IOException {  

        response.setContentType("text/html");  
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  

        String n=request.getParameter("userName");  
        String p=request.getParameter("userPass");  

        if(p.equals("servlet")) {  
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("WelcomeServlet");  
            rd.forward(request, response);  
        } else {  
            out.print("Sorry UserName or Password Error!");  
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.html");  
            rd.include(request, response);  
        }  
    }  
}
```

**WelcomeServlet.java**

```
package java.io;
import java.io.*;  
import javax.servlet.*;  
import javax.servlet.http.*;  

public class WelcomeServlet extends HttpServlet {  

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
            throws ServletException, IOException {  

        response.setContentType("text/html");  
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  

        String n=request.getParameter("userName");  
        out.print("Welcome "+n);  
    }  
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app>  
    <servlet>  
        <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>  
        <servlet-class>Login</servlet-class>  
    </servlet>  
    <servlet>  
        <servlet-name>WelcomeServlet</servlet-name>  
        <servlet-class>WelcomeServlet</servlet-class>  
    </servlet>  

    <servlet-mapping>  
        <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>  
        <url-pattern>/Login</url-pattern>  
    </servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-mapping>  
        <servlet-name>WelcomeServlet</servlet-name>  
        <url-pattern>/WelcomeServlet</url-pattern>  
    </servlet-mapping>  

    <welcome-file-list>  
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>  
    </welcome-file-list>  
</web-app>
```

Comment: why you set package name to `java.io` in  WelcomeServlet? remove it or set full class name in web.xml in `servlet-class` attribute.

Comment: Sounds like you're missing either the servlet mapping or the context, hit http://localhost:8080/ServletExample/Login or http://localhost:8080/ServletExample/WelcomeServlet to see if you can get a response

Comment: thank you , there is a mistake in web.xml. I have corrected. Thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

package java.io;

why u put this line in WelcomeServlet.java.

Answer (score 0):

You're mapping to 'WelcomeServlet' not 'ServletExample'.

Try going to localhost:8080/WelcomeServlet

EDIT: There shouldn't be a trailing slash, sorry!

Comment: I believe you did not intend to put that trailing slash in that url

Answer (score -2):

Make sure ur projrct name is ServletExample.

localhost:8080/ServletExample/index.html